# Support for remote clicker in any PDF viewer?

Tags: pdf, slideshow, education

I use PDF slides for my work. Is it possible to change slides via a remote control (clicker)? What are the PDF viewers in Ubuntu that support this?

Comment: What is ticker?

Comment: You probably won't find a PDF reader with that feature. You only need to remote control your PC from your mobile. KDE connect would do the job. If you want. If you mean a hardware wireless presenter, then any should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Any remote clicker will also work with PDF files. Such devices send a standard "Next" or "Previous" key press, also understood by PDF viewers.